# Would you write "an error was fixed" in scientific work?

Tags: expression-choice, science

I am not sure if

```
Error ABC was fixed by preprocessing algorithm XYZ.
```

is "slang". Can it be written in scientific work? Is there a better way to say it?

The context is in machine learning, where a preprocessing algorithm detects errors that are caused by hardware faults which occur only once in a while.

Comment: rectified, resolved, corrected, removed, depending on context

Comment: @Kris: Thank you! I've added some context. I think rectified could be the right word?

Comment: If you're willing to put your faith in Google's opinion on the matter, at 364,000 results for "error was rectified" vs 280,000 for "error was resolved", I'd say your best bet would be to stick to option No:1 from Kris' array of synonyms.

Comment: @Sycamore It's true that errors are more often 'rectified,' but the choices I offered are not synonyms. It depends on what really was done.

Comment: Duly noted. Array of options it is then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Resolved* may be a better choice.

*Rectified* would mean the code was changed, which I do not know if the preprocessor does -- probably not.

"The error condition was resolved."

Comment: Or "corrected".